# Magento 2 : Product options date saved less then select date while add to cart

Tags: magento2.3

I have just set the time zone from admin configuration.

Time Zone: Gulf Standard Time (Asia/Muscat)
[Time Zone Configuration](https://prnt.sc/nmenfc)

I have a product which has an option for the delivery date and once I am selecting any date and trying to add to cart at that time always 1 date is minus from selected date and save value is always less than one from a selected date  see video for more information 
[Issue Video](https://www.loom.com/share/df64a448caf445f0a17cf8f49c559f87)

This issue faced while we have select **Gulf Standard Time (Asia/Muscat)** Time zone from admin

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?
Any help appreciated Thanks...

Comment: This is really old but maybe can still help simeone
Your module fixes the issue, thx mate.
https://github.com/navinbhudiya/bug-fix-product-options-date-saved-less